# Regex.Escape() unrecognized exception

Tags: c#

I have the following code in `C#`:

```
String str = @"\hello ali how are you? are you fine? hello and hi";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(Regex.Escape(str), @"\hello").Count);
```

I get the following error:

> {"parsing \"\hello\" - Unrecognized escape sequence \h."}

I need to know when a *`\ + (some names)`* exists in my code. I have used `@` for not using escape sequence characters but I still get the mentioned error. I can not understand why this happens!

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(str, Regex.Escape(@"\hello")).Count);`

Comment: Regex does't understand the command \h.  Like \d+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape sequences are used independently in both Strings *and* regular expressions with different meanings.  When you prefix the string literal with `@` you are telling the compiler to interpret the string literally without escape sequences.  However the Regular Expression engine again sees the "\h" and tries to interpret as an escape sequence.

Basically you need to apply *both* the String literal `@` *and* the `Regex.Escape` function to make the `\h` be interpreted as a literal by both parsers:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(str, Regex.Escape(@"\hello")).Count);
```

Answer (score 2):

`\` is used to denote shorthand classes in a regular expression. e.g. `\d` means "any digit", or `\w` means "any word character (alphanumeric characters plus underscores)". The regex engine thinks you're trying to use `\h` as one of these shorthand sequences, but it's not a valid one.

To match a literal `\` in the regex you need to escape it with another one, e.g. `\\`. So in your example your regex would be `\\hello`.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html for more detailed information.

Comment: excuse me, I have used `@` before my string. As I have learned, in paths `\` should be used to replace with `\\` . doesn't it work in regular expressions?

Comment: it's not really the same thing. The @ is telling C# to treat it as a verbatim string (and not apply any additional escaping to it). That string is then passed to the regex engine, which then applies its own rules to it, one of which is about treating `\ ` as a special character.